# Unable to install System.Net.Http in Xamarin portable project

Tags: c#, xamarin

Hello I'm new to Xamarin,
I'm trying to install the System.Net.Http to a Xamarin portable project using NuGet Package Manager.
However, whenever I try to download it I get this error

> Could not install package 'System.Net.Http 4.3.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author

I tried every possible version of the package with no use. Could anybody provide some assistance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the way I managed to solve this problem was weird 
I found a referenced assembly called

.NET --> right click View in object browser --> select System.Net.Http --> clicked add reference to the selected project

and the reference is added

Comment: that is completely bizarre, txs for pointing it out.  you add a reference the same way for 10 years and then all of a sudden this shows up.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to install [Microsoft.Net.Http](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http)? I use it in my PCL Xamarin Forms apps.

Comment: which profile are you targeting? Mine is PCL 4.5, Profile 78

Comment: @AlessandroCaliaro, what the diference between Microsoft.Net.Http and System.Net.Http. Can i to instance client object like system.net.http and to consume a restfull service?

Comment: I installed Microsoft.Net.Http and works fine. Solved!

Answer (score 1):

This can be resolved by changing the profile number for the PCL project.
Personally, i would untick all the unneeded target frameworks by going to: *Project Options -> Build - General - Change Targets*.

In my case i have unticked **Windows Phone silverlight 8** and the profile number got changed from **PCL 4.5 Profile 259** to **PCL 4.5 Profile 111** as shown in this screenshot:

[image: Visual Studio 2017 For Mac]

After doing so System.Net.Http can be added easily.

Comment: This was the solution for me! Thanks so much!